# tf.sparse_to_dense: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, keras-2

My codes:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        import tensorflow as tf
        # x is (None, 10, 2)
        idx = K.cast(x*15.5+15.5, "int32")
        z = tf.sparse_to_dense(idx, 32, 1.0, 0.0, name='sparse_tensor')
        print('z.shape={0}'.format(z.shape))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return x[:, :, 0:2]

drop_out = Lambda(lambda x: f(x), 
                  output_shape=drop_output_shape, name='projection')(reshape_out)
```

x is tensor of `(None, 10, 2)`, where there are 10 indexes/coordinates. Trying to generate a `(None, 32, 32)` tensor `z`. I got the following error:

```
Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'projection_14/sparse_tensor' (op: 'SparseToDense') with input shapes: [?,10,2], [], [], [].
```

How to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The specific error you've seen is trying to say your `output_shape` should be a 1-D Tensor, like `(32,)`, rather than 0-D Tensor as you had there, `32`. But I worried this simple change will not solve your problem.

One thing I don't understand is why your `x` is a 3-D tensor when you said you have just 10 indices. Technically speaking, [`sparse_indices` can be a 2-D tensor at most](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_to_dense). My understanding of `tf.sparse_to_dense` is that it's quite similar to making a sparse tensor. So the number `2` in your `(10, 2)` already decided that the output tensor will be 2-D. The `None`, like variant sample size, should be handled differently.

Following this logic, another problem you may find is the `output_shape` should be `(32, 32)` rather than `(32,)` as the simple fix mentioned above. The length of the tuple should match the shape (last axis specifically) of `sparse_indices`.

With all these in mind, I think a tensorflow only MVCE mimicking your example could be:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(10, 2))
idx = tf.cast(x*15.5+15.5, tf.int32)
z = tf.sparse_to_dense(idx, (32, 32), 1.0, 0.0, name='sparse_tensor')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(
        z, feed_dict={x: np.arange(20, dtype=np.float32).reshape((10, 2))/20})
    )
```

Just to point out: [The `tf.sparse_to_dense` "FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Create a tf.sparse.SparseTensor and use tf.sparse.to_dense instead."](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_to_dense)

Comment: thanks. but now I am stuck in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53694991/keras-tensorflow-how-to-get-differentiable-tensor-from-index-information...